# Facing Radius compilation Error while configuring the CC with arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi-gcc compiler

Tags: linux, gcc, arm, freeradius

I have started compiling the freeradius freeradius-server-3.0.21 using with Marvell Linux Cross Compil with arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi-gcc. I have seen the below warning messages

> configure: error: FreeRADIUS requires libtalloc".

I have tried to install talloc-2.1.0 also but unable to compile the radius server. I request to help me out of this problem.

```
checking for _talloc in -ltalloc... no checking for _talloc in
-ltalloc in /opt/talloc-2.1.0/bin/default... no checking for _talloc in -ltalloc in /opt/talloc-2.1.0/bin/shared... no checking for _talloc in -ltalloc in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu... no checking for _talloc in
-ltalloc in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba... no checking for _talloc in -ltalloc in /usr/local/lib... no checking for _talloc in -ltalloc in /usr/share/doc... no checking for _talloc in -ltalloc in /usr/share/doc/libtalloc-dev... no checking for _talloc in -ltalloc in /usr/share/doc/libtalloc2... no checking for _talloc in -ltalloc in /usr/share/doc/libtalloc2-dbg... no checking for _talloc in -ltalloc in /var/cache/apt/archives... no checking for _talloc in -ltalloc in /var/lib/dpkg/info... no checking for _talloc in -ltalloc in /usr/local/lib... no checking for _talloc in -ltalloc in /opt/lib... no configure: WARNING: talloc library not found. Use
--with-talloc-lib-dir=<path>. configure: error: FreeRADIUS requires libtalloc
```

Comment: "I have tried to install talloc-2.1.0" - You have installed **cross-compiled** version of the `talloc`, haven't you? Please, provide (in the question post) **more details** about your building process and about installed prerequisites.

Comment: Hi , Thank you for reply, I have downloaded the talloc-2.1.0 version. But unable to compile with cross compiler. with following command " ./configure --cross-compile --cross-execute=arm-marvell-linux-gnueabi- --hostcc=arm-none-linux-gnueabi" . Observed the below error messages while compiling   File "./buildtools/wafsamba/samba_utils.py", line 48, in runonce_wrapper
    ret = function(*args)
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory